# Irregularities regarding bounties in my account

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have noticed two irregularities concerning bounties in my account:

1. I have never offered a bounty on [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/6010/does-christ-return-to-heaven-after-the-thousand-year-reign-and-then-return-to-e), but my account shows that I offered a bounty worth 50 reps and these reps were also deducted from me.
2. On manually awarding my first bounty on my own question, the system failed to award me a bronze badge.

Can anyone explain these apparent irregularities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You did, in fact, offer a bounty an that question. You posted it on Oct 6 '13 at 19:39 as a "Authoritative reference needed" bounty. The problem is it was never awarded. You did not select a recipient and no answer qualified for the auto selection when you don't select one manually.

   The reputation cost for offering a bounty is deducted from your account whether you end up awarding it or not.
2. All of your previous bounties show up as having been awarded by the "Community" user, not by you. It looks like you are not selecting the recipient manually (as required for the badge) and instead the bounty is being awarded automatically by the system to the highest upvoted answer that arrived during the bounty period.

Comment: What is causing confusion is, the bounty usually shows on the question but there is no evidence on the actual question of a bounty ever being there.Maby i am missing something.Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Bagpipes There is evidence in two places: ① In your account under bounties offered (where you found it) and ② in the [revision history for the question](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/posts/6010/revisions). What does not exist is evidence of a bounty having been _awarded_, because it never was. It was only offered, not awarded.

Comment: O.K. understood! I see that i have been awarded my missing badge.Thanks!

Comment: @Bagpipes I'm glad you got in squared away, but the badge award is not something I did. You did that just now by actually manually awarding a bounty. It never gave you the badge before because you never actually manually awarded any of the bounties you offered before. Badges sometimes take a few minutes to be awarded, but you only became eligible at all just now.

Comment: Yes, i was not clicking on the bounty award.I only clicked on the accept answer.Problem solved!